# cudaMalloc/cudaMemcpy with embedded objects/structures

Tags: c++, vector, struct, cuda, mpi

I am working on quite a big parallel application using OpenMPI to distribute data among MPI Processses. Using MPI with some serialization library, such as "cereal" makes it very comfortable to pass huge-multi embedded objects around. To give a hint of what I mean by multi-embedded structure, I am currently working with simplified version, such as :

```
// structures for CUDA - this is inside std::vector<struct_multi_data> multi_data_vector
struct struct_multi_data{
    int intended_kernel_block;
    int intended_kernel_thread;
    std::vector<float> data_float;
    std::vector<float> data_int;
    float result;
};

struct struct_unique_data{
    // this structure is shared among all blocks/threads
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};


class Data_object{

// functions
    public:
        Data_object();
        ~Data_object();

        int resize(int multi_data_vector_len, int data_float_len, int data_int_len);
        void set_id(int id);

        int clean(void);
        int get_multi_data_len();
        int get_multi_data(struct_multi_data * data, int vector_element);
        int set_multi_data(struct_multi_data * data, int vector_element);


// variables
    private:
        std::vector<struct_multi_data> multi_data_vector;
        struct_unique_data unique_data;
        int data_id;
};
```

* the above code is simplified, I have removed serialization functions and some other basic stuff, but the overall structure holds

To put it simply, I am moving around the **Data_object**, containing **vector{struct_multi_data}**, which is a vector of structures, where every structure **struct_multi_data** contains some **vector{float}**.

I have a good reason to embed all the data into 1 Data_object, as it simplifies the MPI sending and receiving.

---

**QUESTION**

Is there some comfortable way to move the Data_object to GPU memory using cudaMalloc/cudaMemcpy functions ?

There seems to be problem with regular std::vector. I dont want to rely on *Thrust* library, because I am not sure whether it would work with my MPI serialization solution.

**EDIT QUESTION**
Can I use *managed* for my Data_object, or cudaMallocManaged() to make the data accessible to GPU ?

---

**PLEASE READ**

The size of the Data_object is well defined at the beginning of the program execution. None of the vectors changes size anywhere else, but the beginning of the execution. So why am I using vectors ? this way I can set the vectors size by passing parameters, instead of re-compiling the program to change the data size (such as when the data are defined as arrays).

---

**RESPONSE TO COMMENTS**
1) I think can replace all the vectors with pointers to arrays.

Comment: The one word answer is no.

Comment: This becomes somewhat hard when using std::vector and I think you might have misunderstood how they allocate memory. In this case it would be way easier just to use dynamically allocated arrays (as are vectors!) since at least you'd know what block of memory you need to copy. And you could initialize their size exactly the same way as vectors'.

Comment: Still No. Managed memory can't solve the problem of no being able to use host container classes on the GPU and no CUDA APIs support any sort of "deep copy"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, and the extra sections in this question don't help. `std::vector` is just not intended to work that way: It "owns" the memory it points to, and if you mem-copy it someplace else (even in host memory) and use it from there, you'll just corrupt your memory. Also, the `std::vector` code can't even run on the GPU since it's not `__device__`-code.

What you could do is use an `std::span`, which *doesn't* own the memory, instead of the `std::vector`. If you do that, and the memory is managed, then mem-copying a class might work.

Note I'm completely disregarding the members other than the vector as that seems to be the main issue here.